# I want to execute this script every tot seconds with Ajax without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to execute this script each a given amount of seconds using Javascript Ajax. (The idea is avoiding to reload the page)

This is the script:

```php
include("databaseCONNECTION.php");
$seconds=1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbDatabase .".chat";
$lines = [];
foreach($dbConnection->query($sql) as $row) {
    $line = '<span class="time-message">' . $row['when_send'] . '-' . '</span>';
    $line .= '<label class="nick-message"><strong>' . $row['sender'] . ': ' . '</strong></label>';
    //$lines[] = $line . ": " . $row['message'];
    echo $line . $row['message'] . "<br/><hr/>";
}
```

Comment: u nd to gve us mre info. Your script is in php, you are asking for Ajax, what exactly do you need?

Comment: i am doing a chat, but it doesn't refresh automatically.. so i tought to use Ajax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a basic form you could do something like this using `fetch`

```
setInterval( ()=>{
    fetch( '/path/to/php/script.php' )
    .then( r=>{ 
        return r.text();
    })
    .then( data=>{
        alert( data );
    })
    .catch( err=>{
        alert(err);
    })
}, 1000 * 10 );// every 10s
```

---

If you were to use a utility function such as the following to simplify the creation of DOM nodes you can generate the new content without trying to erase the document initially.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> **Note:** as document.write writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open, which will clear the document.

```
const create=function(t,a,p=null){
    let el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
    let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
    for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || a.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML || a.html;
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.innerText || a.text;
    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
    return el;
};
```

You could then modify your ajax function like this ( untested though )

```
setInterval( ()=>{
    fetch( 'chat-data.php' )
    .then( r=>{ 
        return r.text();
    })
    .then( data=>{
        /*
            Without seeing the HTML this is pseudo-code. Change to suit
            your HTML structure.
        */
        let parent=document.getElementById('TARGET_ELEMENT_ID');
        let record=create(null,{},parent);


        Object.keys( data ).map( key=>{
            let obj=data[ key ];

            create('span',{'class':'time-message','text':obj.when_send},record);
            create('label',{'class':'nick-message','text':obj.sender},record);
            create(null,{'text':obj.message},record);
            create('hr',{},record);
        })
    })
    .catch( err=>{
        alert(err);
    })
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: it works, but there is another problem explained in another question

Answer (score 0):

it give me the data each tot seconds, but i cannot print it in my div... i tried with json_encode, so i rivisited my script:

```
include("databaseCONNECTION.php");
$data = array();
foreach($dbConnection->query($sql) as $rows) { 
    array_push($data, array("when_send" => $rows['when_send'], "sender" => $rows['sender'], "message" => $rows['message']));        
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>

// and this is my javascript script:


<script language="javascript">
                        setInterval( ()=>{
                            fetch( 'chat-data.php' )
                            .then( r=>{ 
                                return r.text();
                            })
                            .then( data=>{
                                for(i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                                    document.write('<span class="time-message">', data[i]['when_send'], '- </span>');
                                    document.write('<label class="nick-message"><strong>', data[i]['sender'], ': </strong></label>', data[i]['message'], '<br/><hr/>');
                                }
                            })
                            .catch( err=>{
                                alert(err);
                            })
                        }, 1000)

</script>
```

Comment: using `document.write` like this is not correct - you need to set the `innerHTML` or `textContent` of the target HTML elements